# Does "comprehend" mean "understand" or "include" in this long sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning, syntax

I really couldn't decide on the meaning of "**comprehend**" in this sentence. Does it mean "**understand**" or "**include/comprise/encompass**", or something else? Could anyone help please?  Many thanks.

> He then told her of Georgiana’s delight in her acquaintance, and of
>   her disappointment at its sudden interruption, which naturally leading
>   to the cause of that interruption, she soon learnt that his resolution
>   of following her from Derbyshire in quest of her sister had been
>   formed before he quitted the inn, and that his gravity and
>   thoughtfulness there had arisen from no other struggles than **what
>   such a purpose must comprehend**.
>
> *from Pride & Prejudice*

Comment: I think it must mean **include, involve**.

Comment: So do I. Thank you for your  word "involve". Because in my mother language, "invlove" makes much sense than "include".  I really feel that "a purpose" could not "understand sth"; but to achieve such "a purpose" involves a lot to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, 'comprehend' means "to encompass," from Latin roots that mean "to hold completely."

Thus, the meaning of the phrase **what such a purpose must comprehend** in this convoluted, 71 word sentence (typical for Jane Austin and other writers of the time) is that he [Darcy] was grave and thoughtful at the inn *only* because of his decision to follow her [Elizabeth] to search for her sister [Lydia].

[Entomology of 'comprehend'](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=comprehend)